# how to select exslt:node-set array?

Tags: xslt

I have a program to select variable by using exslt:node-set
I got error under Firefox as "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed". How to fix this problems?

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="series_color">
<color>#99FF99</color>
<color>#0099FF</color>
<color>#FF6600</color>
<color>#990099</color>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="1"/>
    colorx: <xsl:value-of select="exslt:node-set($series_color/color[$index+1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: I found how to get right color vaiable under xls. <xsl:variable name="colorN" select="exslt:node-set($series_color)/color[$index+1]"/>. But it seems svg rect command does not take fill="{$colorN}".

Comment: @user3533821 **1**. This has nothing to do with your question. **2.** FYI, `<rect height="100" width="200" fill="#FF6600"/>` **is** a valid SVG element - so if you're trying to generate SVG, make sure your XSLT produces this or similar result. **3.** Note also that SVG is XML - specifying a text output for the transformation is not suitable.